# Export tests from TestLink to SilkCentral

Tags: testlink, silktest

I need to export some test cases from **TestLink** to **SilkCentral**. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a tech support related query for the tool vendor.

Comment: @TESTasy, there is a tag [silktest] ... also, there is [visualstudio], [jenkins], etc. also vendor tools ...

Comment: How to import test cases from Excel with images as attachment to Silk Central. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Did a quick Google search and you can export the tests from TestLink into an XML format. You can then open this XML with Excel and use the Office Import capability in Silk Central to import the test cases.